# SELECT STATEMENT IN VARIABLE

Tags: sql-server

Following code is showing error.

```
dECLARE @KK VARCHAR(50);
SET @KK = SELECT RIGHT(1000000+(MAX(JWL_ORID) + 1),6) JWL_ORD_MST FROM JWL_ORD_MST
SELECT @KK
```

error shows .

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

iS there any other way..

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @KK VARCHAR(50);
SET @KK = (SELECT RIGHT(1000000+(MAX(JWL_ORID) + 1),6) 
           FROM JWL_ORD_MST);
SELECT @KK;
```

Or use the non standard assignment `SELECT` statement directly :

```
DECLARE @KK VARCHAR(50);
SELECT @KK = RIGHT(1000000+(MAX(JWL_ORID) + 1),6) FROM JWL_ORD_MST;
```

But, **remove the alias.**

Comment: Your code is Displaying 
'Incorrect syntax near 'JWL_ORD_MST'.'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @KK VARCHAR(50)

-- #1
SET @KK = (SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT(1000000 + (MAX(JWL_ORID) + 1), 6) FROM dbo.JWL_ORD_MST)
SELECT @KK

-- #2
SELECT @KK = RIGHT(1000000 + (MAX(JWL_ORID) + 1), 6) FROM dbo.JWL_ORD_MST
SELECT @KK
```